# Necesito sumar los valores de una tabla creada con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-tabla

He creado una función para crear una tabla cada vez que se presiona el botón contar.

La tabla tiene valores de **Producto, cantidad y Total** quiero sumar todos los totales y poner el resultado en un `input`.

Sé que tengo que hacer un `Array` y usar el método `push` el punto está en que al hacer el `push` pone todos los elementos en un solo elemento del `Array` y no me funciona.

---

Código:

```
$('.op').on('click',function(){ 
 var lista=$('.lista').Val(); 
 var con=$('.contar').Val(); 
 var sum=0; 
 var os=0; 

 switch(lista){
  case 'A': 
   os=1; 
  break; 
  case 'B': 
   os=1.25;
  break; 
  case 'C': 
   os=1.50;
  break;
  default:

  alerta('ingresar valor');
 }

 sum=con*os;

 var tr=$('<tr></tr>');
 var tda=$('<td></td>').text(lista);
 var tdb=$('<td></td>').text(con);
 var tdc=('<td class="sums"></td>').text(sum); 

 tr.append(tda,tdb,tdc);
 $('.table').append(tr);
});
```

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir algo de tu código para entenderlo mejor y darte una respuesta más acorde a tu situación?

Comment: Disculpa lo he escrito en este momento es que el código lo tengo en asa y he tardado un poco en escribirlo emmm vale mira hasta ahí funciona todo y agrega una fila a la tabla y todo ahora lo que quiero hacer es sumar todos los valores de <td class='sum'> y meter el resultado en un input.

Comment: Hola @JhonatanIñiguez, te sirvió la respuesta ?

Answer (score 0):

Hola lo que puedes hacer es crear un `acumulador` y un `array` el `array` por fuera del `click` ya que si lo dejas adentro lo reinicia y así puedes ir guardando los registros de la tabla, edite tu código , revisa este `snipet`, Como no subiste el código de `$('.lista').val();` y  `$('.contar').val();` supuse que son `inputs`

```js
var AcomuladorTotales = new Array();

$('#op').on('click',function() { 

 var lista = $('.lista').val(); 
 var con = $('.contar').val(); 
 var sum = 0; 
 var os = 0; 
 var total = 0;
 

 switch(lista){
  case 'A': 
   os=1; 
  break; 
  case 'B': 
   os=1.25;
  break; 
  case 'C': 
   os=1.50;
  break;
  default:
  alert('ingresar valor');
 }


 
 sum=con*os;
 
 
 // AcomuladorTotales = AcomuladorTotales + sum;
 AcomuladorTotales.push(sum);

 AcomuladorTotales.forEach(function(element) {
  total = total + element;
});

 var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
 var tda = $('<td></td>').text(lista);
 var tdb = $('<td></td>').text(con);
 var tdc = $('<td class="sum"></td>').text(sum); 

 $('.inputTotal').val(total);

 tr.append(tda,tdb,tdc);
 $('.table').append(tr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="lista"> 
<input type="text" class="contar">
<input type="button" id="op" value="Generar tabla">
<br><br>
<table class="table" border="1">
</table>
<br>
<label>Input con los totales</label>
<br>
<input type="text" class="inputTotal" disabled>
```

Lo que hice fue crear un `array` y un acumulador, realice el `push` al `array` y recorría el `array` cada vez que hacia el `click` y al recorrerlo lo iba sumando y agregando al `input`.